# Bluetooth Low Energy Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

why it doesn't works?
The "#" is correctly send but not read (The other device read the character and send it). I think i can't execute the two following function in the same time but why?

```
    Read_Data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Write
            Data_BLE_Write("#");

            //Read
            Data_BLE_Read();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But if i separe Data_Ble_Read and Data_Ble_Write with two buttons, it's operate so i don't understand why??
My functions :

```
private void Data_BLE_Write(String Caract){
    if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic_W =
                mGattCharacteristics.get(3).get(1);
        final int charaProp = characteristic_W.getProperties();

        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic_W;
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                    characteristic_W, true);
        }
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
            String str = Caract;
            byte[] strBytes = str.getBytes();
            characteristic_W.setValue(strBytes);
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCaracteristic(characteristic_W);
        }
    }
}
    private String Data_BLE_Read(){
    Data_Read_Ble = "";
    if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                mGattCharacteristics.get(2).get(6);
        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
            // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
            // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                        mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
            }
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                    characteristic, true);
        }
        Data_BLE_Write("&");
    }
    return Data_Read_Ble;
}
```

Comment: "But if i separe Data_Ble_Read and Data_Ble_Write with two buttons, it's operate so i don't understand why??" <-- Probably because there's then enough delay between the write and the read. When they are under the same button the read happens right after the write.

Answer (score 1):

The ble stack allows only one task at the same time, so basically you are aborting the write task with your read task. You should wait with the next task until the task before has finished, in your case you should wait until the property is read, before starting with the write.

Hope this helps.